# Phase diagram for water

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-diagram

The phase diagram for water shows that at very high pressure and room temperature water becomes ice. Is it possible to this confirmed this by experiment?

Comment: Are you asking has it been confirmed by experiment (yes, yes it has...) or how to design your own experiment to do that?

Comment: Yes, water *does* become ice at room temperature and very high pressure, but for this discussion, "very high pressure" means greater than 950 MPa, or 9400 atmospheres, or 137800 psi.  http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_phase_diagram.html

Comment: My interest is how do you design an experiment to confirm the presence of ice under these severe conditions

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to "do" it, but the observation of it might be related to the fact that we found "type VII" ice (see the table of the various crystalline structures of ice on wikipedia/ice) inclusions in diamonds. (O. Tschauner, S. Huang, E. Greenberg, V. B. Prakapenka, C. Ma3 et al., « Ice-VII inclusions in diamonds: Evidence for aqueous fluid in Earth’s deep mantle », Science, vol. 359, no 6380,‎ 9 mars 2018, p. 1136-1139)